# names of leaves of nested list in R

Tags: r, list, nested, names

I want to check if two nested lists have the same names at the last level.

If `unlist` gave an option not to concatenate names this would be trivial. However, it looks like I need some function `leaf.names()`:

```
X <- list(list(a = pi, b = list(alpha.c = 1:5, 7.12)), d = "a test")

leaf.names(X)
[1] "a" "alpha.c" "NA" "d"
```

I want to avoid any inelegant grepping if possible. I feel like there should be some easy way to do this with `rapply` or `unlist`...

Comment: it looks like `reshape2::melt(X)` would probably be easiest

Comment: maybe `d=reshape2::melt(X);   apply( unique(d[,-1]), 1, function(row) row[which(!is.na(row))[1]])` but it's not very elegant

Comment: anyone know of a simple base R answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
leaf.names <- function(X) names(rlang::squash(X))
```

or

```
leaf.names <- function(X){
  while(any(sapply(X, is.list))) X <- purrr::flatten(X) 
  names(X)
}
```

gives

```
leaf.names(X)
# [1] "a"       "alpha.c" ""        "d"
```

Comment: anyone know how to do this succinctly in base R?